# How to remove same values in LinqToSql But get same rows count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have about 20000 rows data in Table in db.

I want to get 3 rows data in this table , but I don't want to get same rows.

Example code:

```
var SampleTable = (from v in db.Article
                   select new Item
                   {
                       Name = v.Name
                   });

var distinctItems = SampleTable.GroupBy(x => x.Name ).Select(y => y.First());
var threeItem = distinctItems.Take(3).ToList();
```

If I use `var distinctItems = SampleTable.GroupBy(x => x.Name ).Select(y => y.First());` and get 3 rows.

It work, but large data rows will take a large time to do `GroupBy`.

But if I take 3 rows in `SampleTable` first, then remove same rows.
If remove rows happen that will cause my rows count not 
meet the requirements count.

Have a better way to do?

Comment: "It work, but large data rows will take a large time to do GroupBy" - define "large"?

Comment: @MitchWheat more than 20000 rows data. It take 2~4 sec to do GroupBy.

Comment: Are you running on a 486?..............

Comment: @MitchWheat It's a Article type Table in db, I thought GroupBy in Sql Server will take large time. And row will increase fast in future.

Comment: probably it will take way less time than if you bring in the data in-memory and then do remove and groupby

Comment: 2-4 secs seems an extraordinary long time. Are you sure you are using Take(3) and not accidentally returning all rows?

Comment: @sgmoore Because it "GroupBy" all rows than take 3 rows, it cause take long time